# Complex exponentiation identity $a^{z}b^{z} = (ab)^z$ for $a, b > 0, z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

This is likely a trivial question, but I can only recall a list of general failures for the complex exponentiation rules from by CA class and not any "here's a list of the 'regular' rules that work in these and these settings". In any case, in which situation does $a^zb^z = (ab)^z$ hold for general $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a, b > 0$ two positive real numbers? If I am not mistaken, the definition $z^w = e^{w\mathrm{log}(z)}$ for $\mathrm{log}(z) = \mathrm{ln}|z| + i(\mathrm{Arg}(z) + 2\pi k), k\in\mathbb{Z}$ gives:

$$a^zb^z = \exp(z\mathrm{log}(a))\exp(z\mathrm{log}(b))\Leftrightarrow$$

$$a^zb^z = \exp(z(\ln|a| + 2\pi i k_1)\exp(z(\ln|b| + 2\pi i k_2)\Leftrightarrow$$

$$a^zb^z = \exp(z\ln(ab) + 2\pi i (k_1+k_2)z)\Leftrightarrow$$

$$a^zb^z = (ab)^ze^{z2\pi i (k_1 + k_2)}$$

for $k_1, k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. And I am not really sure how you can get rid of the last $e^{z2\pi i (k_1 + k_2)}$ term.

Comment: There is no such term for $a,b>0:$ the log is just the ordinary $\ln,$ and $$e^{z\ln a}e^{z\ln b}=e^{z\ln a+z\ln b}=e^{z\ln(ab)}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Would you add the $2\pi i k$ for a complex $a$? If so, why in principle could we omit $2\pi i k$ for real $a$?

Comment: The *definition* of $a^z$ for $a>0$ is simply $a^z=e^{z\ln a}.$ There is no "omission". As for your (multivalued) definition of $z^w$, I am not sure it is usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of (common) convention. We can read for instance in *[Complex Analysis](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=CHEL/385)* by L. Ahlfors:

> **(L. Ahlfors):** By convention the logarithm of a positive number shall always mean the real logarithm, unless the contrary is stated. The symbol $a^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary complex numbers except for the the condition $a\ne 0$, is always interpreted as an equivalent of $\exp(b\log a)$. If $a$ is restricted to positive numbers, $\log a$ shall be real, and $a^b$ has a single value. Otherwise $\log a$ is the complex logarithm, and $a^b$ has in general infinitely many values which differ by factors $e^{2\pi i nb}$.